# Isomorphic (SmartClient) ListGrid Won't Allow Div Tags to Overflow (Conflicts with Twitter Bootstrap's multiselect)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, smartclient

I've got an application in which a SmartClient ListGrid and a Twitter Bootstrap multiselect co-exist.  Unfortunately, when the multiselect drops down and attempts to overlap the ListGrid, it gets cut off.  The issue appears to be ListGrid's refusal to allow div tags to overflow over it.

I dug through the documentation and played with various settings, but could not figure out how to change this behavior.  Any ideas?

The code snippet below demonstrates the problem with a generic div tag. I need the sample div tag to be on top of the ListGrid.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
        .my-style {
            overflow: visible;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
    <!--Deleted: jQuery & Isomorphic includes --> 
    <script>
        $(document).ready( function() {
            isc.ListGrid.create({
                top:0, left:100,
                fields: [ {name:'X'}, {name:'Y'} ],
                items: []
            });
            $('#main').html('<div class="my-style">This is a test</div>');
        });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main" class="my-style">
        A sample div tag
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you produce a jsFiddle example of the problem? I don't know if you can load all your required libraries into that, but a demonstration of the issue might make it easier for people to advise a work around

Comment: Maybe you need to make the overflow important // overflow: visible !important;

Comment: i think the issue can be resolved by adjusting `Z-index` css property of multi select and grid. have a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SmartClient sets very high zIndex values on the DOM elements that it generates for widgets. The [DOM Integration & Third-party Components](http://www.smartclient.com/docs/9.1/a/b/c/go.html#group..domIntegration) page explains a few options for fixing the zIndex issue with third-party widgets:

1. Many widget libraries provide a mechanism to render the widget inside an existing HTML element. I don't know if the Bootstrap multiselect widget can do this, but if so, there is example code given on that documentation page on how to render the third-party widget within a custom SmartClient `Canvas`.
2. Whenever the multiselect widget is shown, you can call `getZIndex(true)` on the `ListGrid` and dynamically set the multiselect element's zIndex to a higher number.

   This approach assumes that the `ListGrid` is a top-level widget (`getParentCanvas()` returns `null`). If the `ListGrid` is within some other SmartClient widget, then you will need to get the zIndex of the top-level widget.
3. As an unsupported option, you can modify the `_nextZIndex`, `_SMALL_Z_INDEX`, and `_BIG_Z_INDEX` class properties to make SmartClient use lower zIndex values.

   I haven't tried this, but looking through the source code, the bringToFront() `Canvas` method sets the widget's zIndex to the `_BIG_Z_INDEX`, which it also increases.

There are two other options:

1. It looks like the Bootstrap multiselect widget is very similar to a SmartClient multi-select `SelectItem` with multipleAppearance:"picklist". See [the Multi-Select example](http://www.smartclient.com/docs/9.1/a/system/reference/SmartClient_Explorer.html#multiSelect). You can certainly style the `SelectItem` pickList to look exactly like the Bootstrap multiselect widget if you wanted.
2. SmartClient supports embedding SmartClient widgets within existing HTML elements via the `htmlElement` attribute.